# Escaping special characters in sqlplus

Tags: database, oracle, passwords, escaping, sqlplus

I have an oracle database with password

```
+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX
```

If I try to connect with it using

```
sqlplus -S -L USER/'"+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX"'@host @script.sql
sqlplus -S -L USER/'+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX'@host @script.sql
sqlplus -S -L USER/"+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX"@host @script.sql
```

they all fail with error

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

However the same password works in sql developer. How do I get sqlplus to work given that this password cannot be changed?

Comment: What operating system are you using? My suggestion would be to try `sqlplus -S -L 'USER/+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX@host' @script.sql`

Comment: Using linux ubuntu. That is also failing with ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

Comment: Certain special characters on certain operating systems do not work from the command line, because they have special meaning to that particular OS. In most cases there is no work around. It will work from SQL Developer because the OS isn't interpreting the content of the password as it passes through the application. In my experience, the only special character that works universally from the command line is the underscore ( _ ). In your case, I would guess that one of the characters is being read as end-of-line and the password is being truncated, leading to the ORA-01017 error.

Comment: @pmdba But the echo command works fine 

echo "+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX"

+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX

If the OS had an issue with one of the characters, it would not work right?

Comment: All I can say is that it isn't a guarantee. I would recommend trying Oracle Wallet to hold the password instead of putting it right in the command line (which is generally not a good idea anyway, even if it doesn't throw an error).

Comment: The syntax for sqlplus would be to use doublequotes (") around the password section. However most shells will also interpret doublequotes, so they do not get to the sqlplus executable with how you typed it.  


In a shell you need to escape the entered double-quote against the shell as \" or or also wrap with single-quotes ('):  `sqlplus -S -L USER/\"+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX\" @host @script.sql` or `sqlplus -S -L 'USER/"+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX"' @host @script.sql`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, another idea to try would be to use a here-doc:

```
sqlplus << EOHD
CONNECT USER/+oS0pocWEpvaX++CN3]8nM‘2eX@host
@script
EXIT
EOHD
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. Tried skipping the password and entering at the prompt and that did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Login as SYS from the backend and reset the password of the user without any special characters.

Change it to a preferred password without special characters from your script.